# Block specific ipad apps from Internet using a Hotspot locked down with UFW

Tags: firewall

My goal is to be able to use an Apple ipad online but block specific apps from network connections. I want to create proprietary products with these apps and don't want this content stored on their cloud.

One online solution was to go into ipad settings and block cellular for any specific app but many of us do not have cellular on the ipad and must use wifi for internet access. And, there is no wifi blocking equivalent feature per app.

Another proposed solution is Apple approved vpn firewall apps. The problem with this is you have to buy a service and all your content truly isn't blocked it's still sent to the vpn unnecessarily.

Another proposed solution I found suggests to use Screen Time to disable apps. Apps are disabled, but not their network connections. Wireshark proved to me that Screen Time Apps (although disabled from use when launched) still start making network connections after a blocked launch attempt.

Another proposed solution I found was that I should turn off iCloud storage but some apps are not using iCloud so this is not a complete solution.

So, I'm trying to do it by customizing a hotspot with ufw firewall rules where these rules will block these apps.

What steps do I take to do get an app specific rule set for ufw?

Should I block hosts by putting them in /etc/hosts file? If so, how do I get all the hosts?

Should I block by ip address? How do I get all the ip addresses so I can form this rules?

My tools of disposal at this time are: wireshark, ufw, and a computer for a hotspot.

I prefer to use ufw and the hotspot, but if not through hotspot with ufw how about some other way that has the same end goal?

Answer (score 0):

Enroll the devices in a mobile device management system. Whitelist and blacklist apps as desired.

Probably there exist firewalls that can do application identification sufficient for this purpose. However, I don't know how to do so with UFW. The real trick is identifying different apps that all use the same public clouds.

Comment: Do you know of a specific Apple ipad MDM that is free that blocks connections of specific apps?